# How do sites like ipmango.com work?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I mean how can a mere website tell my I.P. address and the ports that are available to forward? For example what do I have to do in order to incorporate this kind of facility on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A website must know what your IP address is, otherwise how else would it know where to send the data packets back to?

Also it does not know which ports "are available to forward". It only knows which port your request originates from (this port is random).

Your computer may be making many requests simultaneously from various programs, so knowing the correct IP address makes sure the data gets back to the right computer, and knowing the correct port makes sure it goes to the correct program (or more specifically, the correct process).

Comment: Thanks. that somewhat helped (y).